# How to add special price in new order email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

**How can I add special price in email "New order" template?**

Product block in email template:
`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}`

This is a product row with price.
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/price/row.phtml`

Now the price is the product of the number of pieces and the final price of the product (qty * final price).

I would like to show the regular price and the special price (result of qty * regular price and result of qty * special price, or just item regular price and special price).

I know how to extend block, make a plugin etc. but I don't know how to get special price from this item.

Anybody help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you have to do some work before completed:

Copy special price from product to order item

- Create new database column to **quote_item** and **sales_order_item**
- Copy special price from product to quote_item when customer have added product to cart.
- Copy special price from quote_item to order_item when customer submitted order.
- Update the template vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/price/row.phtml which allow you render order item information to the order item line.

How to update the row.phtml

- Create a layout which named **sales_email_item_price.xml**
- Reference the block **item_price**
- Update the block template by using code block below

```
<referenceBlock name="item_price">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">yourvendor_module:templatename.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answear. I think this is correct way. After mentioned steps but adding column (regular_price) to tables (quote_item and sales_order_item), we should to extend item interface and add new method - getRegularPrice() which we can use it for displaying old price in email template (if highest then item price) and e.g. in order view.

Comment: You shouldn't extend the interface, you should use extension_attribute instead. Because the API won't know your extend.

Answer (score 1):

Product special price is by default $product->getSpecialPrice().

But as special price has date limits etc so once order is placed we shall not use code like $product->getSpecialPrice()  to pull.

Step1 : Populate special price at the time order is placed :
https://m.academy/blog/programmatically-add-column-magento-2-sales-order-database-table/

Step 2 : once you have this then you shall get the price in $_item  object.

I have not tried the code but logically this shall be the approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answear.